# Paste Special Run time error 1004 method range failed

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using the following VBA code and assigned it to a button:

```
Sub pastespecial ()

ActiveSheet.Range("A4:X400").Copy
Activesheet.Next.Range("A4:X400").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
ActiveSheet.Next.Range("A4:X400").PasteSpecial paste:=xlPasteFormulas

ActiveSheet.Previous.Activate

Application.CutCopyMode = False

MsgBox "Data has been copied Successfully"

End sub
```

It was doing it before but start making issues now.
I am getting

> run time error 1004 pastespecial method of Range class Failed

Thanks in advance

Comment: Before what/when? Please share the modifications that have been made.

Comment: You probably need `Activesheet.Next.Activate` before you paste.

Comment: when i debug the error it highlights
ActiveSheet.Next.Range("A4:X400").PasteSpecial paste:=xlPasteFormulas

this part

Answer (score 0):

If the active sheet is the **first** sheet, the sub will fail on:

```
 ActiveSheet.Previous.Activate
```

because there is no previous sheet.  If the active sheet is the **last** sheet, the sub will fail on:

```
 Activesheet.Next.Range("A4:X400").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

because there is no next sheet.  Your code works for me if there is both a worksheet before and after the active sheet.

*(make sure there is nothing else to cause an error like merged cells or protection.)*

Comment: Is there a difference in coding for 32 bit excel and 64bit excel, as my code is working fine in 32 bit excel. But making issue with 64 bit excel

Comment: It's highlighting the second pastespecial option for error. I have both previous and next sheet available.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is working for me..

```
Sub pastespecial ()

ActiveSheet.Range("A4:X400").Copy
Activesheet.Next.Range("A4:X400").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
ActiveSheet.Range("A4:X400").Copy
ActiveSheet.Next.Range("A4:X400").PasteSpecial paste:=xlPasteFormulas

ActiveSheet.Previous.Activate

Application.CutCopyMode = False

MsgBox "Data has been copied Successfully"

End sub
```